# A convex quadrilateral separated by its diagonals into 4 triangles with congruent incircles must be a rhombus.

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

The question is in the title, and I need a hint or a solution:

> A convex quadrilateral is separated by its diagonals into 4 triangles. Suppose these triangles have congruent incircles, then show that the quadrilateral must be a rhombus.

I can see that the quadrilateral whose vertices are incentres (of the 4 triangles described in the problem) is a rhombus. Looks like I have to show that this rhombus is a square. But I am not able to prove it.

I would also appreciate a reference which deals with problems of this type. I found [a reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.00870.pdf) with similar problems and would love to see more.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why "quadrilateral whose vertices are incentres is a rhombus"? That was not immediately obvious to me, so I'm asking you to show your working.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Flip the construction in the question around. Instead of starting with the convex quadrilateral to get the congruent circles, we start with the congruent circles and hope to get a quadrilateral.

Consider a configuration where we have 2 lines that intersect at $X$, and we place 4 congruent circles that are tangential to both lines.
Suppose we pick a point $A$ on a line, and draw a tangent to the circle to reach point $B$, draw a tangent to the next circle to reach point $C$, draw a tangent to the next circle to reach point $D$, draw a tangent to the next circle to reach point $E$.
**Show that $ A = E$ (meaning we have a quadrilateral) iff the lines are perpendicular (and hence show that they bisect each other).**

**Corollary:** "The incircles are congruent" iff "the diagonals are perpendicular and bisect each other" iff "the quadrilateral is a rhombus".